# Simplifying Polygons and MultiPolygons for Visualization

Tags: python, geopandas, visualisation

I completed a computation with [Canadian Census data](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm) and discovered, when trying to visualize the results with `Bokeh 2.0.2`, that the `Polygon` and `Multipolygon` paths were very high resolution with a point every 30 meters or so.

[image]

My first strategy was to use `GeoPandas`' built-in `Shapely.Simplify` to simplify the geometry but the test results were less than satisfactory, and the full rendering of the dataset still wouldn't complete in my notebook regardless.

```
gdf_simplified["geometry"] = gdf.simplify(tolerance=50000, preserve_topology=True)
```

[image]

I was wondering what some next steps could be to try to visualize this geometry? Should I try `matlibplot`? Are there are other topology preserving algorithms to try?

Answer (score 4):

1) try much lower tolerance.

2) If you want an algorithm preserving the topology in between the shapes, you should look for TopoJSON. Otherwise, every other implementation simplifies each polygon individually, causing the gaps and overlaps where none are expected. Since you have GeoPandas GeoDataFrame, you can use `topojson` [package](https://github.com/mattijn/topojson/) to do the simplification. Then you can do this roundtrip GDF -> TopoJSON -> Simplify -> GDF:

```
import topojson as tp
topo = tp.Topology(gdf, prequantize=False)
gdf_simplified = topo.toposimplify(5).to_gdf()
```

It just may take a while to compute topology first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to work outside GeoPython, mapshaper ([Mapshaper.org](https://mapshaper.org/) / [Mapshaper on Github](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference)) works very well, and fast for such purposes.

Simply store your GDF as a Shapefile, GeoJSON, etc. and use it in mapshaper.

When working from the commandline the basic prompt (on windows) looks like that:

> cd 'your_workingdirectory'
> mapshaper in.shp -simplify dp 20% -o format=shapefile out.shp